# Storyboard Not Loading View Controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode8.2

I have updated my Mac to High Seirra version 10.13.1. After the update a storyboard is not working correctly.

The views in the storyboard are shown as blue outlines instead of showing the view detail.

I am using Xcode 8.2.1.

[image: blue outlines of views]

Answer (score -1):

It's a temporary issue, just quit the XCode and reopen again.